# What ruby on rails methods return a full data set before filtering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

**Database:** PostgreSQL 9.6.6
**Rails Version:** 5.0.2
**Ruby Version:** 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]

I am working on debugging a piece of application code that returns a subset of data and one of the problems that I'm seeing is that Rails' Active Record is returning all data before filtering. The line of code that I'm debugging is:

```
@al ||= CC.find(@e.mcc.first.cc_id).additional_languages&.split(',') || []
```

The `.first` method retrieves all data from the table and then pulls the first record. There are over 91 million rows in the table and I would like it if the query didn't pull all of those back prior to grabbing the `.first` row.

Is there a list or some documentation that will tell me which rails methods return a full result set and which ones do not?

Comment: "`.first` retrieves all data from the table and then pulls the first record" - no, it doesn't. At least on my machine. Here it correctly applies `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: It could happen that `mcc` in `@e.mcc` is not a normal `has_many` relation. But is instead a custom method which fetches some data (or something like that). In which cast, it's this `mcc` method that is responsible for reading all that data, not `first`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. Using `.find_by()` solved the issue I was having. The line of code now looks like this:

```
@al ||= CC.find_by(id: (MCC.find_by(export_id: @e.id).cc_id)).additional_languages&.split(',') || []
```

Thank you all for your help.